# How to remove coolant hose from T piece

Tags: coolant, radiator, opel, hose

I noticed that on an Opel astra F some of the radiator hoses were connected to a T piece using a kind of hose clamp that's unfamiliar to me:
[image: T piece hose clamps]

There's no screw/spring or other hardware on the bottom. It just looks like a crimped ring. Am I right in assuming that the only way to get these off is to cut them, probably with a grinding wheel of some sorts. And to replace them with a more traditional hose clamp after replacement of the hose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to cut them - difficult but possible with sidecutters, they do make special cutters for these, but you can grind them : be very careful where the sparks go : cover everything...

For replacement use a good quality hoseclamp making sure it is sufficiently wide.